# Is there a way to use a Python set as the data type for an SQLAlchemy Column?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, set

How can I restrict the values of a column in a MySQL database to be one or more elements of a pre-specified set using SQLAlchemy? (Ideally, I want a way to use MySQL's [`SET` datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html).)

## Example

### Context

I have an experiment involving taking measurements from many individuals over several days. Many of the individuals entered the experiment after it started (so data from the first few days are missing) and occasionally an individual drops out (data on the last few days are missing). It's also possible that some individuals have missing measurements in the middle of the experiment.

I want to make a table that stores some information about each individual and lists which days their measurements were taken.

## Code

I was hoping something like the following would work, since this is roughly how SQLAlchemy [supports](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) `Enum`s.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sql
experiment_days = {'day_1', 'day_2', 'day_3'}
sql.Column('days_measured', experiment_days)
```

Unfortunately, I get this error message:

```py
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'
```

I was expecting to get a `Column` with a SET data type that can take on values `day_1`, `day_1,day2`, `day_1,day_3`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL `SET` datatype is supported by the [MySQL dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.SET):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql

class MyTable(Base):

    ...

    myset = Column(mysql.SET('day_1', 'day_2', 'day_3'), ...)
```